# LaTeX porting *.eps images with eps2pdf and german umlauts (mutated vowel)

Tags: pdf, latex, eps, diacritics

I draw a use case diagram with MagicDraw and save it as EPS file. Now I want to integrated it into my TeX file by using eps2pdf. It works so far, but the picture includes german umlauts like ä,ö or ü and they will be shown as "?" (question marks).

What could I do to solve this problem?

Greetings,
Lony

Important packages:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to embed all fonts in the PDF file?

As far as I remember, this code should do it:

```
ps2pdf14 your_image.eps
```

And BTW, you can check if your pdf embeds all fonts using `pdffonts`

Comment: The ps2pdf way do not work. How could i use pdffont? I checked the fonts with Adobe Reader and found out that its Arial encoded with ANSI. Maybe the problem lays in MagicDraw?

Comment: Yes, check it. Maybe it is some problem with encoding. Maybe try UTF8. But all fonts are embedded in your PDF file, right?

Comment: All fonts are embedded like Adobe Reader said. The problem is I could not chance the outcome of MagicDraw meaning the encoding. Seams I have to use png instead ;(.

Comment: I'd try using `iconv` on the ps file and change whatever encoding is listed in there. May or may not work, but if it does …

Comment: iconv is nice! Never heard from it.

But I found out that the output of Magic Draw contains the error! So there is no solution from encoding side. I wrote an bug report, we will see what they do.

Thanks for your help!